# Associativity of operators in C

Tags: c, associativity

From the book which I have read:

Associativity can be of two types:
**1-Left to Right**
Left to Right associativity means that the left operand must be unambiguous.Unambiguous in what sense? It must not be involved in evaluation of any other sub-expression.
**2-Right to left**
same as above.

Now please read the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* no of item purchased>1000 then discount of 10% else full price */
int main()
{
  int n;
  float r,p,d,t;

  printf("Enter the no of item purchased");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter the price per item");
  scanf("%f", &r);

  if(n > 1000)
  {
    p = n * r;
    printf("Price before discount = %f\n", p);

    d = 10 / 100 * p; //please have a carefull look at d
    printf("discount offered is = %f\n", d);

    t = p - d;
    printf("total price after discount = %f\n", t);
  }
  else
  {
    p = n * r;
    printf("total price is = %f", p);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As given in above code **"d=10/100*p"** it follows L-->R associativity as p is calculated previously involved in evaluation of other expression.
Now changing the d **"d=p*10/100"** this case correctly calculates the discount but above one gives zero as answer.

Can anyone please explain associativity in context to above example.

Comment: Please read the duplicates before posting them again. And don't tag a C question [tag:c++].

Comment: I think this may help you: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: since `10` and `100` are integers, the calculation uses integer division: `10/100 == 0`.

Comment: @tly: Please, do not use the comments section for giving the answer.

Comment: thank you @JesperJuhl for the link,the explanation in the book was not that good :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I was not able to find answer related to this from other post, should I delete it?

Comment: the posted code contains: `int n;
  float r,p,d,t;`    For ease of readability and understanding, variable names should be meaningful and indicate contents or usage (or better, both)  The variables, even in the current context, are meaningless.

Comment: this line: `Now changing the d "d=p*10/100" this case correctly calculates the discount but above one gives zero as answer.` this calculation is using `integer` math.   I.E. no remainder.  So when using `d=10/100*p` the 10/100 is performed first.  since no remainder, the result is 0. and 0 multiplied by any number is still 0.  This is one of the `gotchas` of integer math.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both multiplicative `*` and `/` are left-to-right operators. They even have the same precedence.

Therefore, your expressions can be re-written like so without changing their meaning:

```
d = (10 / 100) * p
d = (p * 10) / 100
```

Since `10 / 100` is an integer division with the result `0`, hopefully now you can see the difference.

Answer (score -4):

C's arithmetic `*` (and also `-` and `+`) operators are associative just as they are mathematics:

These lines evaluate to `true`:

```
A * B * C == (A * B) * C == A * (B * C);
```

<sup>(or any permutation of A, B, C, because `*` is also commutative—i.e., `x*y == y*x` is true)</sup>

However, this in general is not true:

```
A / B / C == (A / B) / C == A / (B / C);
```

Comment: This is extremely misleading, particularly as one of the operands in question has a floating-point type (and floating-point arithmetic is **not** associative). Furthermore, you did not answer the question.

Comment: `A / (B / C)` is different to `(A / B) / C`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why does it matter if it's floating point or not?

Comment: @Geremia: Because floating-point operations are not associative.